# Is this the local coordinates transformation giving the Schwarzschild metric?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I'm a bit unsure about the following:

From the Schwarzschild metric:

$$A(r)=\left(1-\frac{2GM}{rc^2}\right)$$
$$ds^2=A(r)c^2dt^2-1/A(r)dr^2-r^2d\theta^2-r^2\sin^2\theta d\phi^2$$

Doesn't the following local transformation give back the Minkowski spherical metric, where the barred coordinate means it is not differentiated:

$$x_0=A(\bar{r})^{1/2}t$$
$$x_1=A(\bar{r})^{-1/2}r$$
$$x_2=\bar{r}\theta$$
$$x_3=\bar{r}\sin(\bar{\theta})\phi$$

The metric in x coordinate is euclidean, hence the solution in x are straight lines. We just need to invert the local transformation : but for r, we get from the second equation inversion :

$$r=A(\bar{r})^{1/2}x_1$$ a locally linear transformation

The barred r is obtained by reversing the globalized transformation :

$$x_1^2\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)=r^2\Rightarrow r^3-x_1^2 r+r_s x_1^2=0$$

This is a cubic which posseses 3 roots.

Comment: Wat do you mean by "not differentiated" ?  It sounds like you want to treat e.g. $\bar{r}$ as if it was a constant.

Comment: Not sure what $\bar{r}$ means but you definitely cannot make a coord transformation from Schwarzschild to flat space

Comment: The coordinates transformation is written as $x'^\mu=f^\mu_p(x^\nu)$. P is the point at which the function is defined. So when you derive towards x it does not touch p. Then express p as the barred coordinates ?

Comment: MathJax Hint: Use `\left(,\right)` and `\left[,\right]` and not simple `(,)` and `[,]` to adjust vertically their height to the content. See the edit I made in your question.